# i tried every solution and stii doesnt work css file in odoo

Tags: odoo-16

/*my **openerp**.py*/

```
{
    'data': [
         'views/css_loader.xml',
     ],
 }
```

/*css_loader.xml*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <openerp>
     <data>
         <template id="assets_backend" name="my_library assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
             <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my_library/static/src/css/my_styles.css"/>
             </xpath>
         </template>
     </data>
 </openerp>
```

/*livre_view1.xml*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
        ...
        <record id="library_livre_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Library Livre Form</field>
            <field name="model">library.livre</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <sheet>
                        <div class="e">
                            <h1>
                            dsq
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
</odoo>
```

/**manifest file**/

```
{
    'name':'my_library',
    'website':"dsqdsq",
    'data':['views/livre_view.xml'],
}
```

the css file cant load

i tried a lot of solution none of them work i have odoo v16
i can't see where is the problem